# How to properly add import path to webpack 2 for foundation sass

Tags: webpack, zurb-foundation

I'm having trouble understanding the correct way to add foundation scss to my import path using webpack 2. As you can see in the the [Compiling Manually section](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html#compiling-manually) of the foundation docs, I need to add 'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss' to the load path so webpack2 can find it:

> Next, add the framework files as an import path. How you do this
>   depends on your build process, but the path is the same regardless:
>   packages_folder/foundation-sites/scss

I've read lots similar questions and the documentation for webpack2, but still can't seem to get it working. This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.js', './src/scss/main.scss'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss"),
      "node_modules"
    ],
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".scss"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { // scss loader for webpack
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ // define where to save the file
      filename: 'styles.css',
      allChunks: true
    })
  ],
}
```

As you can see I added the `resolve.modules` key and tried to add `path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss")` in addition to the default `node_modules` directory.

I expected this to allow me to `@import foundation` in my main scss file, but I get an error when building:

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/main.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed:
@import 'foundation';
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: foundation.
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? How am I supposed to properly add the foundation directory to the import path?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but this worked:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.js', './src/scss/main.scss'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { // scss loader for webpack
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss")]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ // define where to save the file
      filename: 'styles.css',
      allChunks: true
    })
  ],
}
```